# variable $it in Gradle task : Reference : Gradle in Action book

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Whilke going through the book I came across this line

> Groovy automatically exposes an implicit variable named it to indicate
>   the loop iteration index.

from the Gradle in Action book, chapter 2 Listing 2.1

The line says that $it represents loop iteration index. However when I try add 
 `$it` to println statement of task yayGradle0/1/2, it prints out the task and not the index. I'm confused about this behavior. Please guide.

```
3.times{
    task "yayGradle$it" <<{
        println 'Gradle rocks--->>>'+"$it"
    }
}
```

The output after running task yayGradle0 is :

```
Gradle rocks--->>>task ':yayGradle0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `it` variable in a different context than [presented in the book](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-in-action-source/blob/master/chapter02/listing_02_01-dynamic-task-and-task-dependencies/build.gradle#L9-L13). In your case you are working in the context of the task's `Closure`. Therefore, `it` represents a different object, a `org.gradle.api.Task` instance. It would be helpful to reference [Closure delegation strategies](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy). Please also see [Appendix B in the book](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/gradle-in-action/appendix-b).

Answer (score 1):

(edit after rereading)

`it` is the  index in loop.

From groovy shell

```
  3.times  {
    println "${it}"
  }

0
1
2
```

In your code there is another closure, it becomes variable to that closure (which is task name)

Following example uses explicit variable at top level.

```
3.times{ counter->
    task "hello${counter}" <<{
        println 'Gradle rocks--->>>'+" ${it}  ${counter}"
    }
}
```

$gradle hello2 gets following output.

> Task :hello2
>   Gradle rocks--->>> task ':hello2'  2

references

[novice](http://www.java2novice.com/gradle/dynamic-tasks/) 
[groovy closures](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html)